# Online survey method: Redesigning existing website for an agency

Tags: user-research, surveys

The situation is that our customers usually hears about our services from others in the city or country rather than finding us through our website. But as our website feels outdated and the provided services have expanded, we want to redesign it. But before that we want to make an online survey, to give to our clients, so they can fill them out. But my questions is:

What would be more valuable to understand, what they think about our current website, what to change, what to include etc. or ask questions that are highly related to the services we provide, like:

What first comes to your mind when thinking about our services?
What do you like least/most about our services?
And many similar about the services itself...

Or maybe ask both?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Piotr answered.

- Before asking the customers, analyse the internal sales information:
  which services are sold the most, is the business owner happy with it
  or wants to promote the different services or products.
- Analyse the competitors: which services/products do they provide, how does your
  agency looks like in comparison with the competitors.
- I would avoid Yes/No questions
- I would ask how do the customer perceive your agency
  (multi variant    question): structured, fun, responsible, expensive,
  cheap etc.
- Which brands do they associate you with? (BMW, McDonalds, Apple,
  Samsung etc)
- What's the conversion action? Writing the inquiry or pressing the "Buy now" button? Ask which obstacles did they have before completing the desired action? (Lost in navigation, didn't understand the content, didn't find the contact information)
- Maybe the agency website has a secondary value for the customers (inspirational blog, entertaining content, shared research articles etc)

After accomplishing this analysis, you will know, which services to promote, how the customers perceive your agency and what are their expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Designing research is an extremely interesting activity related to UX, it is worth predicting what results might be obtained. And then estimate the approach as needed.

What will the specific results give? what results?

**Question regarding services**

- can be helpful in business context (which services generate the most
  revenue?)
- where are the bottlenecks?
- asking for services will also provide a lot of information on how to
  promote them, how to present them, sell them etc.
- will provide results that will help you analyze your image and quality from the customer's perspective

**Question regarding current website**

- provide specific design guidelines (design context)
- suggestions in the context of information architecture design?
- will define areas that can be improved / discarded / replaced

---

The scale of the project seems to be important here (i.e. is it about creating a new system from scratch or editing an existing one?
The decision in the context of what to ask and how to get on with the project is multi-context (implementation, scale, budget, time, strategy) etc.